# $\|x\|_b=\sum^\infty_{i=1}{1\over 2^i}|x_i|$, is it equivalent to the supremum norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my question:

Let the $\|\cdot\|_b$ on $c_0$ be a norm defined by:

$$\|x\|_b=\sum^\infty_{i=1}{1\over 2^i}|x_i|$$

Is $\|\cdot\|_b$ equivalent to the supremum norm?

---

So I know that if $\|\cdot\|_b$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ are equivalent, that means there exists positive $C,C^\prime$ such that:

$$\|x\|_b\leq C\|x\|_\infty \text{ and } \|x\|_\infty\leq C^\prime \|x\|_b$$

I am thinking that it is false that they are equivalent. Let us assume that $x\in c_0$ and that $\|x\|_\infty=\|(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)\|_\infty = |x_k| \geq (\sum{1\over 2^i})|x_k|=(\sum{1\over 2^i}|x_k|)\geq(\sum{1\over 2^i}|x_i|)=\|x\|_b$ therefore $\|x\|_\infty\geq \|x\|_b$... so I am thinking that $C^\prime$ does not exist. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $c_0$ is the space of sequences with limit $0$?

Comment: @GenericNickname correct

Comment: Consider sequences $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$, where the $i$ component is $1$ and others zero.

Comment: @J.A.L Great suggestion... in that case, $\|(0,...,0,1,0,...)\|_\infty=1$ and $\|(0,...,0,1,0,...)\|_b={1\over 2^i}$. So $\|x\|_b={1\over 2^i}\leq 1=\|x\|_\infty$ (always true), but there does not exist a fixed $C>0$ such that $\|x\|_\infty=1 \leq C{1\over 2^i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|x\|_\infty = : x_k, k \in \mathbb{N}, k > 0$. Then 
$$ 2^k \| x \|_b = 2^k \underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} | x_i | = 2^k (\frac{1}{2} | x_1 | + \frac{1}{2^2} | x_2 | + ... + \frac{1}{2^k} | x_k | + ...)$$ $$ = 2^{k-1} | x_1 | + 2^{k-1} |x_2| + ... + |x_k| + ... \geq |x_k| = \|x\|_\infty $$
Therefore, $$ \|x\|_\infty \leq 2^k \| x\|_b. $$
In conclusion, $C' = 2^k$.